# How can I show Arabic dates in a block?

Tags: 7, datetime

I have used Drupal7 and I want to add Arabic date in Hijri formate; I have used the Calendar Systems module, but it doesn't add dates as block. How can I implement `hook_block()` to show dates in Hijri format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its approved now I just added the new release yesterday

[Hijri](https://www.drupal.org/project/hijri)

> This is a smart module that basically extends Drupal's display date to provide Hijri Date integration with Drupal core date field and with other Drupal contributions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [sandbox module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2392971) that should allow you to format dates this way:

> This is a smart module that basically extends Drupal's display date to
>   provide Hijri Date integration with Drupal core date field and with
>   other Drupal contributions.
>
> This module is integrated very well with Views module. You can use it
>   to display Hijri date instead of Gregorian date or you can have them
>   both by mention "[had to remove Arabic text]". Also this module coming with Hijri block
>   that will showing Hijri today date on your website wherever you want
>   to show today date in your header for example.

I do not know when/if this module will be approved and promoted to a full project.